# How to interpret a joblib traceback within Python 3.x?

Tags: python, python-3.x, algorithm, parallel-processing, joblib

**Objective:** to apply [**`joblib`**](https://pythonhosted.org/joblib/generated/joblib.Parallel.html#joblib.Parallel) tools to a Python 3.x script. I am new to `joblib` and thought I would see if someone could help me to interpret the traceback to get meaningful results. I have kept to *`n_jobs=1`* simply to help with the traceback, obviously in practice something like > 2 would be ideal.

Given a `dataset` like the following:

```
dataset = [['Milk', 'Onion', 'Nutmeg', 'Kidney Beans', 'Eggs', 'Yogurt'],
           ['Dill', 'Onion', 'Nutmeg', 'Kidney Beans', 'Eggs', 'Yogurt'],
           ['Milk', 'Apple', 'Kidney Beans', 'Eggs'],
           ['Milk', 'Unicorn', 'Corn', 'Kidney Beans', 'Yogurt'],
           ['Corn', 'Onion', 'Onion', 'Kidney Beans', 'Ice cream', 'Eggs']]

one_ary = np.array([[0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1],
                    [0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1],
                    [1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
                    [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1],
                    [0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0]])

cols = ['Apple', 'Corn', 'Dill', 'Eggs', 'Ice cream', 'Kidney Beans', 'Milk',
        'Nutmeg', 'Onion', 'Unicorn', 'Yogurt']

df = pd.DataFrame(one_ary, columns=cols)
```

I use the following code, error to follow:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-17-c7221dc109b5> in <module>()
      1 from math import sqrt
      2 from joblib import Parallel, delayed
----> 3 out = Parallel(n_jobs=1, verbose=100, pre_dispatch='1.5*n_jobs')(delayed(sqrt)(i) for i in apriori(df))

D:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\joblib\parallel.py in __call__(self, iterable)
    777             # was dispatched. In particular this covers the edge
    778             # case of Parallel used with an exhausted iterator.
--> 779             while self.dispatch_one_batch(iterator):
    780                 self._iterating = True
    781             else:

D:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\joblib\parallel.py in dispatch_one_batch(self, iterator)
    623                 return False
    624             else:
--> 625                 self._dispatch(tasks)
    626                 return True
    627 

D:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\joblib\parallel.py in _dispatch(self, batch)
    586         dispatch_timestamp = time.time()
    587         cb = BatchCompletionCallBack(dispatch_timestamp, len(batch), self)
--> 588         job = self._backend.apply_async(batch, callback=cb)
    589         self._jobs.append(job)
    590 

D:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\joblib\_parallel_backends.py in apply_async(self, func, callback)
    109     def apply_async(self, func, callback=None):
    110         """Schedule a func to be run"""
--> 111         result = ImmediateResult(func)
    112         if callback:
    113             callback(result)

D:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\joblib\_parallel_backends.py in __init__(self, batch)
    330         # Don't delay the application, to avoid keeping the input
    331         # arguments in memory
--> 332         self.results = batch()
    333 
    334     def get(self):

D:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\joblib\parallel.py in __call__(self)
    129 
    130     def __call__(self):
--> 131         return [func(*args, **kwargs) for func, args, kwargs in self.items]
    132 
    133     def __len__(self):

D:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\joblib\parallel.py in <listcomp>(.0)
    129 
    130     def __call__(self):
--> 131         return [func(*args, **kwargs) for func, args, kwargs in self.items]
    132 
    133     def __len__(self):

TypeError: a float is required

from math import sqrt
from joblib import Parallel, delayed
out = Parallel(n_jobs=1, verbose=100, pre_dispatch='1.5*n_jobs')
(delayed(sqrt)(i) for i in apriori(df))
```

Error:

How is that I can make use of `joblib` in the following code:

````
from itertools import combinations
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd


def apriori(df, min_support=0.5, use_colnames=False, max_len=None):
    """Get frequent itemsets from a one-hot DataFrame
    Parameters
    -----------
    df : pandas DataFrame
      pandas DataFrame in one-hot encoded format. For example
      ```
             Apple  Bananas  Beer  Chicken  Milk  Rice
        0      1        0     1        1     0     1
        1      1        0     1        0     0     1
        2      1        0     1        0     0     0
        3      1        1     0        0     0     0
        4      0        0     1        1     1     1
        5      0        0     1        0     1     1
        6      0        0     1        0     1     0
        7      1        1     0        0     0     0
        ```
    min_support : float (default: 0.5)
      A float between 0 and 1 for minumum support of the itemsets returned.
      The support is computed as the fraction
      transactions_where_item(s)_occur / total_transactions.
    use_colnames : bool (default: False)
      If true, uses the DataFrames' column names in the returned DataFrame
      instead of column indices.
    max_len : int (default: None)
      Maximum length of the itemsets generated. If `None` (default) all
      possible itemsets lengths (under the apriori condition) are evaluated.
    Returns
    -----------
    pandas DataFrame with columns ['support', 'itemsets'] of all itemsets
    that are >= `min_support` and < than `max_len` (if `max_len` is not None).
    """

    X = df.values
    ary_col_idx = np.arange(X.shape[1])
    support = (np.sum(X, axis=0) / float(X.shape[0]))
    support_dict = {1: support[support >= min_support]}
    itemset_dict = {1: ary_col_idx[support >= min_support].reshape(-1, 1)}
    max_itemset = 1

    if max_len is None:
        max_len = float('inf')

    while max_itemset and max_itemset < max_len:
        next_max_itemset = max_itemset + 1
        combin = combinations(np.unique(itemset_dict[max_itemset].flatten()),
                              r=next_max_itemset)
        frequent_items = []
        frequent_items_support = []

        for c in combin:
            together = X[:, c].sum(axis=1) == len(c)
            support = together.sum() / float(X.shape[0])
            if support >= min_support:
                frequent_items.append(c)
                frequent_items_support.append(support)

        if frequent_items:
            itemset_dict[next_max_itemset] = np.array(frequent_items)
            support_dict[next_max_itemset] = np.array(frequent_items_support)
            max_itemset = next_max_itemset
        else:
            max_itemset = 0

    all_res = []
    for k in sorted(itemset_dict):
        support = pd.Series(support_dict[k])
        itemsets = pd.Series([i for i in itemset_dict[k]])

        res = pd.concat((support, itemsets), axis=1)
        all_res.append(res)

    res_df = pd.concat(all_res)
    res_df.columns = ['support', 'itemsets']
    if use_colnames:
        mapping = {idx: item for idx, item in enumerate(df.columns)}
        res_df['itemsets'] = res_df['itemsets'].apply(lambda x: [mapping[i]
                                                      for i in x])
    res_df = res_df.reset_index(drop=True)

    return res_df
````

I appreciate any and all help with the above script making use of `joblib`.

Answer (score 0):

As per documentation, the **`pre_dispatch`** parameter ought yield an integer instead of a float.

> `pre_dispatch: {‘all’,` **`integer`** `, or expression, as in ‘3*n_jobs’}`

One may challenge the possible string-expression's interpretation with something more wild and dangerous, like an expression of `"max( 2, int( 1.5 * n_jobs ) )"`

---

Epilogue:

One may also object that a **`joblib`** service, when using the `multiprocessing`-based backend resorts to a full process-instantiation, which costs immense costs ( in both [PTIME] and [PSPACE] dimensions of the computing complexity ) has obviously poor reward for doing so, if nothing but a `math.sqrt(i)` results are asked for. A proper cost-reward evaluation ought be a reasonable step here ( [Ref.: **Overheads** and related sections in **Amdahl's Law Criticism**](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/18374629/3) ).